# Get on what tile has mouse clicked

Tags: java, mouse, swing, chess

I am writing a chess game using Java and Swing, And I wanted to get the tile position on which a mouse clicked. I searched through internet, but all of them were really off, and never accurate. When I clicked on a tile's first half, it said it was tile 1, but on the second half, it said it was tile 2, but it was still tile 1. So I was wondering, how can I do it?

My tile size is (75, 75) This is the code I've written for tileX: `Math.floor((double)evt.getX() / 75)`, and this is the code I've written for tileY: `Math.floor((double)evt.getY() / 75)`.

Code for drawing:

```
ImageIcon l_winter = new ImageIcon("/Users/user/NetBeansProjects/chess/src/b/bibe/assets/winter/light.gif");
        ImageIcon d_winter = new ImageIcon("/Users/user/NetBeansProjects/chess/src/b/bibe/assets/winter/dark.gif");
        ImageIcon l_wood = new ImageIcon("/Users/user/NetBeansProjects/chess/src/b/bibe/assets/wood/light.png");
        ImageIcon d_wood = new ImageIcon("/Users/user/NetBeansProjects/chess/src/b/bibe/assets/wood/dark.png");
        String theme = th;
        int color = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 600; i = i + 75) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 600; j = j + 75) {
                JLabel panel = new JLabel();
                panel.setText(null);
                panel.setSize(75, 75);
                if (color == 0) {
                    if (theme.equals("wood")) {
                        panel.setIcon(l_wood);
                    } else if (theme.equals("winter")) {
                        panel.setIcon(l_winter);
                    } else {
                        panel.setText("notexture");
                    }
                    //panel.setBackground(new Color(white[0], white[1], white[2]));
                    color = 1;
                } else {
                    if (theme.equals("wood")) {
                        panel.setIcon(d_wood);
                    } else if (theme.equals("winter")) {
                        panel.setIcon(d_winter);
                    } else {
                        panel.setText("notexture");
                    }
                    //panel.setBackground(new Color(black[0], black[1], black[2]));
                    color = 0;
                }
                panel.setLocation(j, i);
                getContentPane().add(panel);
            }
        if (color == 0) {
            color = 1;
        } else {
               color = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: "When I clicked on a tile's first half, it said it was tile 1, but on the second half, it said it was tile 2, but it was still tile 1." That sounds like you're off by one half tile. Presumably you tried adding 0.5 to each value before flooring it? How did that work out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason for your problem is that the 0:0 position of your content pane you attach your tiles to and the 0:0 position of the object you've attached your mouse listener to (that code seems missing from the question) do not line up. As DMGregory pointed out, adding the offset factor to the mouse positions should do the trick.

But there is a better solution for your problem.

Each of your chess tiles is a separate JLabel (which you confusingly call "panels", which is [a different thing in swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html)). JLabels can have mouse listeners themselves. Those listeners will only fire for events which happen within that label. That means you can assign individual mouse listeners to each label instead of just one mouse listener for everything. That way you can leave the calculation which label was clicked to the Swing framework.

First, create a mouse listener class which takes information about the tile its supposed to handle in its constructor:

```
public class TileMouseListener implements MouseListener {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public TileMouseListener(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Click on " + x + ":" + y);
    }
    /* ...implementation of the other mouse listener methods... */
}
```

Then assign a new instance of that mouse listener to every JLabel you want to be able to react on mouse events happening to it.

```
panel.addMouseListener(new TileMouseListener(i, j));
```